# Change off contents with themes in Yii

Tags: php, yii, themes

My problem is the next: when I create an application in Yii (with 'classic' theme) the contents of layouts are in URL/protected/views/layouts and this is perfect for me, when I install another theme (bootstrap in this case) the layouts are dependent of the theme and the basic layouts are in URL/themes/bootstrap/views/layouts, and this is a problem for me.

First: Because the aplication only have to manage modules (several) so I want the general content in the general app.

Second: I need work to try a theme

Third: Because in future the theme should be conditionated by User, User selection, and module.

I know that the view prelation is action->controller->theme->module->parent module->default-> none

So I think that it should be so easy as

```
public $layout='main';
```

in the top off the SiteControler,(/protected/controlers) but the 'main' layout that gets is the bootstrap one.

In order to modularize all the aplication I want to have and independent theme for the "principal" aplication and for each module (in several cases will be the same), and of course whitout remake the menu for each one.

I suposse that it is dependent of the default URLs that you configure,

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');
```

in /protected/config/main.php. Or other 'URL configurations'.

Somebody has an idea how may maintain the content indepedent of the themes in 'principal' aplications and modules.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current theme in the controller (or anywhere before calling `controller->render`) by using:

```
Yii::app()->theme = 'yourThemeId';
```

Hope it helps